# Changing the main view using the NSUserDefaults and the settings bundle

Tags: iphone, view, settings, nsuserdefaults, skins

I have a game on the App Store, and for the next version I am working on having an option in the settings to use different skin.  So for example, lets say I choose the basketball option.  I would want the app to show the basketball .xib instead of the default view controller.

How would I do that? There would be about 4-5 different skins.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing your UI programmatically and not using a xib file as I believe it is impossible to accomplish what you are after with a xib.

If you are deadset on using a xib, create 5 identical sets of subviews and name them accordingly, then programmatically hide/unhide them when necessary.

This seems much more cumbersome and hard to manage when faced with an option of just creating the elements yourself in code.